# BigQuery - Google Sheet file format unavailable anymore when creating table from Drive

Tags: google-bigquery, google-drive-api

Since September 15 BigQuery is not proposing anymore the `GOOGLE_SHEET` file format when creating a table in a database from Drive.
Instead there are new format types as: Avro, JSONL, CSV, Parquet, ORC, and Cloud Datastore backup.

When creating a table by pasting the URL of the spreadsheet with the format CSV or Avro BigQuery sends an error message: `Failed to create table: Undefined parameter - ERROR_MESSAGE`

Someone is dealing with the same issue or has a solution ?

Best,

Comment: I'm getting the same cryptic error when using JSON, on a simple file I upload...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It turned out I had a database with the same name already uploaded. (Note: not sure if played a role, but I also did a hard refresh on my browser on the BQ page)

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment.

Comment: Sure, but it could also be an answer in which perhaps OP is trying to save it under the same name.

Comment: I understand that this is possible, but Answers should be reserved for when you believe you are actually providing an answer. Use comments for narrowing down to the answer. You could have shared your experience and ask if he believes that could be the issue. Then the Answer would be an explanation of how to solve the issue.

Comment: noted for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Are the column names on the Google Sheet in a format that can be supported by BigQuery?

I was getting the same error message, but it was caused by the column names on Google Sheet being in Japanese.

If this rings a bell, check it out!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30351432)